Django prefetch_related nested filter
Got classes of Student, StudentGroup, Pair(double lesson), Mark and a queryset:
class Student(models.Model):
    student_group = models.ForeignKey("StudentGroup", ...)
    ...


class StudentGroup(models.Model):
    ...

class Pair(models.Model):
    pair_time = models.TimeField(...)
    pair_date = models.DateField(...)
    student_group = models.ForeignKey("StudentGroup", ...)
    ...

class Mark(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey("Student", ...)
    pair = models.ForeignKey("Pair", ...)

queryset = (
        Student.objects
        .select_related("student_group")
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "student_group__pairs",
                queryset=(
                    Pair.objects
                    .order_by("-pair_date", "pair_time")
                    .select_related("subject")
                    .prefetch_related(
                        Prefetch(
                            "marks",
                            # This is what I need to filter.
                            queryset=Mark.objects.filter(student_id=**???**),
                            to_attr="student_marks"
                        )
                    )
                    .all()
                ),
                to_attr="student_pairs"
            )
        )
        .all()
    )

I need to filter marks by student_id, binding pair and marks (not just get student's marks). How can I do it? Tried F, Q, Subquery, but I can't get how to use'em.

UPD
Now my code looks like this.
class StudentDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = (
        Student.objects
        .select_related("student_group")
        .prefetch_related(
            Prefetch(
                "student_group__pairs",
                queryset=(
                    Pair.objects
                    .order_by("-pair_date", "pair_time")
                    .select_related("subject")
                    .prefetch_related("marks")
                    .all()
                ),
                to_attr="student_pairs"
            ),
        )
    )
    template_name = "students/one_student.html"
    context_object_name = "student"

And HTML (students/one_student.html) file looks like this
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Student {{ student.name }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
            <p>{{ student.surname }}</p>
            <p>{{ student.name }}</p>
            <p>{{ student.father_name }}</p>
            {% for pair in student.student_group.student_pairs %}
            <p>{{ pair.subject.title }} {{ pair.pair_date|date:"m.d.Y" }} Marks:
                {% for mark in pair.marks.all %}
                    {% if mark.student_id == student.id %}
                    {{ mark.mark_value }}
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}

So I managed to filter Student's Marks via template {% if %}. In terms of small groups (30 students) that won't be a problem and will work fine. But I want to aggregate Marks on db level.

UPD_2
Ended up overloading get_object() method to get pk from kwargs and filter by pk. If there is any more smart solution - please let me know

But the Marks are attached to a single student? Why exactly do you need to marks through student_group__pairs?

Because I need to show pairs and student's marks for pair. But there can be no marks for pair, and I still need to show pair. So I can't access pairs through marks. I need to do it through group.
